# Creating square responsive box with 4 elements per row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

MARKUP::

```
<div class="alumni">
   <div class="alumni-list col-xs-3">
      <div class="innerBg" ng-style="{'background':'url('../dummyimage.png')'}">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="alumni-list col-xs-3">
      <div class="innerBg" ng-style="{'background':'url('../dummyimage.png')'}">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="alumni-list col-xs-3">
      <div class="innerBg" ng-style="{'background':'url('../dummyimage.png')'}">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="alumni-list col-xs-3">
      <div class="innerBg" ng-style="{'background':'url('../dummyimage.png')'}">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS::

```
.alumni {
max-height: 280px;
padding: 10px;
overflow: auto;
}
.alumni-list {
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 0px 5px;
}
.innerBg {
height: 56px;
max-width: 56px;
background-size: cover;
border-radius: 4px;
background-position: center center !important;
}
```

alumni container contains 4 alumni-list. Irrespective of screen size, all alumni-list should come in square shape. This is what I tried so far and I'm using bootstrap 3.

Comment: And what problem(s) are you experiencing with this attempted code, where is it failing? *How* is it failing?

Comment: Current code seems to be working just fine, can you please elaborate more on what you wish to achieve.